# Google Sheets Regex Match all URL between two strings (In a paragraph)

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I have try to build my regex, to using Google Sheet to extract the domain url from any paragraph:

```
Website: https://www.interprism.co.jp/  => interprism.co.jp
Website: https://growupwork.com  => growupwork.com
Email: contact@interprism.com website: None  => interprism.com
HP: onetech.jp  => onetech.jp
Web:interprism.jp/index.html  => interprism.jp
```

I have tried with this look ok, `=iferror(regexextract(A11,".+?[@|www.](.*\n?)( )"))` but not match all case, any one can help me on this?
Best Regards
Nim

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
=iferror(regexextract(A11,"(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/?]+)"))
```

---

- `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `http` matches the characters http literally (case sensitive)
- `s?` matches the character s literally (case sensitive)
- `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `:` matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
- `\/` matches the character / literally (case sensitive)

**Non-capturing group `(?:[^@]+@)?`**

- `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^@]+`
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `@` matches the character @ literally (case sensitive)

**Non-capturing group `(?:www\.)?`**

- `?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `www` matches the characters www literally (case sensitive)
- `\.` matches the character . literally (case sensitive)

**1st Capturing Group `([^:\/?]+)`**

- Match a single character not present in the list below `[^:\/?]+`
- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `:` matches the character : literally (case sensitive)
- `\/` matches the character / literally (case sensitive)
- `?` matches the character ? literally (case sensitive)